# Advanced Formula

Tags: formula

- If Probability <= 10 show Low
- if Probability >10 AND <=40 Show Medium
- else High..

-Getting "Low" Any How-

Below is My Formula :-

```
 IF( Probability <=10, "Low",IF(Probability >10 && Probability <=40 , "Medium","High"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field you're using is a percentage, it's represented as a decimal in formula's, so you should use `IF(Probability <= 0.1, "Low", IF(Probability > 0.1 && Probability <= 0.4, "Medium", "High"))`

Note however, that the check for `Probability > 0.1` is kind of redundant, because if Probability is lower or equal to 0.1, it'll already be handled by the first if. So your formula should be: `IF(Probability <= 0.1, "Low", IF(Probability <= 0.4, "Medium", "High"))`